# Remove file and symbolic link vs. overwriting the file

Tags: bash, symlink

I was reading through some source code recently that updated the code on a server. Instead of just writing this to update `myfile`:

```
mv myfile.inactive myfile
```

There was this:

```
rm myfile
ln -s myfile.inactive myfile
```

What is the difference? Why would you want to do it the second way?

`myfile` may be an executable, or a currently running process, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first version rename the `myfile.inactive` into `myfile`. After that command there is no `myfile.inactive` anymore

the second creates an symlink to the `myfile.inactive`. So this file is still there. When you remove (`rm myfile`) the file you only remove the symlink. Keep in mind, if you change the myfile it is also changed in myfile.inactive.
This version is good to change easily the version you are using. e.g. myfile.debug, myfile.live, myfile.version1, myfile.version2 ... you only need to change the symlink to one of the files to "activate" the one you want.

Comment: If `myfile` is a currently running process, it is not a good idea to `rm myfile` because the OS may require to read some part of the executable file.